# Intel DriverInstall issue on HP ProLiant server DL580G5

Tags: installation, hyper-v, nic, intel, adapter

Given: A HP ProLiant server to be used for Hyper-V server (R 2)

Problem: The server has a HP NC364T quad port card, which actually is an Intel 1000 Pro adapter. We are stuck getting this adapter properly working.

We need to get it working with:

- 2 trunks of 2 ports each
- one of them fully vlan "aware" (without filtering anything - so that Hyper-V can do the VLAN filtering).

So far we did:

- Install the server
- Install latest PSP. Problem here - tool does not work to set up teaming.

We tried to install the latest ProWin pack from Intel - the drivers there are a LOT more current (26th of Marrch 2010, 9.13.41.0). The intalled driver (Microsoft) is ancient (march 2009, 9.13.4.10)

A driver update fails both on command line (pnputil) as well as the PortLock device manager executable. No informatoin is provided. the ANS toolset can not create teams (fails with error - again, no reason provided), I know of no logs and the event log has no information either.

Questions:

- What are the best drivers to use?
- How do we actually install them?
- How can we then set up teaming and how do we set up the VLAN behavior wanted?

Answer (score 3):

I would stick with the HP/PSP setup.

It seems like something went wrong with the network driver installation, or an older driver was installed.  The current package is [cp012043.exe](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3454575&swItem=MTX-7088fb62607a438898598c2e4f&prodNameId=3562405&swEnvOID=4064&swLang=8&taskId=135&mode=4&idx=2), version 9.13.16.0 and the files are:

01/29/2010  01:50 PM             8,285 cp012043.xml
06/29/2009  08:55 AM           317,728 cpqsetup.exe
01/29/2009  10:14 AM               107 cp_data.xml
01/27/2010  12:33 AM           121,440 e1000msg.dll
01/27/2010  12:33 AM            18,885 e1e6232e.cat
01/27/2010  12:33 AM             2,745 e1e6232e.din
01/27/2010  12:33 AM           194,622 e1e6232e.inf
01/27/2010  12:33 AM           285,200 e1e6232e.sys
07/21/2009  01:58 PM               176 install.xml
01/27/2010  12:33 AM            36,472 NicCo36.dll
08/11/2009  12:51 PM           512,512 nicdrvr.dll
01/29/2010  01:16 PM            78,528 NicInE6.dll

Comment: Have seen the PSP have an issue witha component of the NIC package and only install part of it. A second attempt insytalled all and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with Greg here, the NIC teaming code is HP's own and will expect the PSP-provided driver package. Regarding your 'vlan "aware"' NIC, do you mean 'unaware' really? i.e. it's not used directly by Windows (i.e. no VLAN tagging, no IP) but bridged through to HV for it's own virtual switch to apply tagging to?

Comment: exactly. so far the concept is to use the psp internal mechanism and create a new virtual nic for every tag - not a good approach. I would prefer to have tagging handled totally within hyper-v for the (teamed) external trunk LAN. How?

Comment: I'm a VMWare guy to be honest but the way ESX does it is that you expose a 'bare' NIC (or team) to it, it then creates a virtual switch which you then create vlan-tagged port groups on and link vNICs to those port groups - that way one multi-vlan trunk can handle all of your various VM's vNIC needs - there must be a HV equivilant??

Comment: Hyper-V works almost the exact same way, except when you bond a NIC to the Hyper-V virtual switch it takes over the NIC. If you want Windows to access the NIC, Hyper-V can create a virtual adapter that's connected through the virtual switch.